# traceview used with webapplication

Tags: c#, iis, trace

Has anybody been able to view Trace messages from webapplication in TraceView?
I am using System.Diagnostincs.Trace.Write ....
but no matter what filter i choose in TraceView i cann't see any message...
(Compiled in debug mode, both TRACE and DEBUG enabled)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  Okay, I think I've actually found what you need:  MSDN has instructions on how to use SvcTraceViewer.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx  which would seem to fit the bill.

In your asp.net app, go to trace.axd, you're trace messages will be there.  If your asp.net app is at http://bob.com/woot then go to http://bob.com/woot/trace.axd and you'll see your trace messages.  There are settings in the web.config you have to set in order to access the trace remotely.

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <trace 
    enabled="true" 
    requestLimit = "10"
    pageOutput="false"
    traceMode="SortByTime"
    localOnly = "true"
  />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```